# Handling the error of someone entering a non integer variable Java

Tags: java

I am writing a program that takes user input of an integer and of a string and performs operations on the string. I have created the program and it works fine, my issue is that I am now trying to handle the error of someone entering a non-integer value for userInput, and I am not sure how to do so. I have tried working with Try Catch statements, but I keep getting error messages for the userInput variable when I do so.

What I want to do is **set the** boolean inputError **to true** when userInput is **not an integer**, so that my while loop repeatedly asks the user to input an integer until they do.

```
public class Q3 {
public static void main(String[] args)
{   
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean inputError = false;

    try{
        System.out.print("Please enter a number between 5 and 10, inclusively: ");
        String userInput1 = in.nextLine();
        int userInput = Integer.parseInt(userInput1);
    }
    catch(InputMismatchException e)
    {
        inputError = true;
    }

    // If userInput is not between 5 and 10, set the boolean inputError to true.
    if (userInput < 5 || userInput > 10)
    {
        inputError = true;
    }

    // Repeatedly ask for user input if they do not enter a number between 5 and 10.
    while(inputError)
    {
        System.out.print("Error. Please enter a number between 5 and 10, inclusively: ");
        userInput = in.nextInt();
        in.nextLine();
        if (userInput >= 5 || userInput <= 10)
        {
            inputError = false;
        }
    }

    // Take user's input for the string.
    System.out.print("Please enter a string of length 6 characters: ");
    String textToChange = in.nextLine();
    int length = 6;
    String printArray = "";
    String wordsOdd = "";
    String finalConcat ="";
    String transitionString="";

    // Print error if text is not 6 characters long.
    while(textToChange.length() != 6) 
    {
        System.out.println("Error! Enter a string of length 6.");
        textToChange = in.nextLine();
    }
```

Comment: what is your actual question? what errors do you get with try-catch? how did you implement the try-catch?

Comment: @Stultuske I have update my code to reflect what I had tried. I am getting the error "userInput cannot be resolved to a variable". I think it is because of the scope, but I am not sure and have tried declaring it outside the catch which doesn't work either.

Comment: your problem is of scope. you declared userInput as a local variable in your first try block, meaning it doesn't exist anymore after that try block is executed and finished

Comment: @Stultuske even when I declared it outside, I then got the error "variable may not be initialised", so I am still unsure of what fix it needs. Can you advise please? Thank you for your help.

Comment: so give it a default initialization. String userInput = null;  before the first try block where you use it, and replace your current String userInput = ... with userInput = ...

Comment: @Stultuske Thank you! I tried that and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the variable "userInput" is declared inside the `try-catch` block which means that after the end of this block will not exist. What you should do is initialize them on the start of your main method so that they can be accessed globally from any code block inside the main method

```
int userInput = 1; // Set default initialisation. 
String userInput1 = "";

try {
  NumberFormat.getInstance().parse(userInput1);
  userInput = Integer.parseInt(userInput1);
}
catch(ParseException e) {
  inputError = true; //not a number
}
```

Comment: this doesn't really address the problem he had in his implementation.

Comment: @NickAth thank you. I did this and initialised inputError to a default value in main, and it worked.

Comment: @LukeByrne with my second comment you should be able to solve your issue

Comment: @NickAth It is always recommended to not just post code but also elaborate on why/how the code solved the problem. Keep in mind that answers here are not only for the person asking, but also for the rest of the world who faces the same problem.

Comment: @Ivar you are right, but I think that the needed explanations have already been given in the comments section, anyway I will try to update my answer :)

Comment: @NickAth Explanations have been given yes, but answers should be self-containing. And comments are not for answers and could be removed at any time. Thanks for elaborating. :) +1

Answer (score 0):

You need all the code that checks the validity of the input inside the loop:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean inputError = true;
int userInput = 0;

while (inputError) {
    try {
        System.out.print("Please enter a number between 5 and 10, inclusively: ");
        String userInput1 = in.nextLine();
        userInput = Integer.parseInt(userInput1);
        inputError = (userInput < 5 || userInput > 10);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        inputError = true;
    }
    if (inputError)
        System.out.println("Wrong input");        
}
System.out.print("Please enter a string of length 6 characters: ");
..................................
```

The above loop will never finish until a valid integer is passed as `userInput`.

Comment: the above gives an error when I type in a string to the console for userInput.

Comment: @LukeByrne Good catch it is `NumberFormatException` and not `InputMismatchException`  that must be caught. See my edit.

Comment: thanks for updating. I have one other issue which is that while it does repeat, it does not print an error message if the wrong input is entered. I would like to ask at first that they enter the integer, then print an error if they enter a wrong value. Is there a way of doing that with try/catch? I tried it but have not been able to do it right.

Comment: @LukeByrne see the edit in my answer with the message